# completely reinstall bluetooth

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am having issues with the bluetooth installation. The Interface (settings > bluetooth) is always showing the »searching« state. If the interface is open and i run `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` it actually shows a list of devices - but that one doesn't update until I rerun the command. Additionally Bluetooth devices do not connect properly, or not at all.

The special thing here is, that there is not »no native Bluetooth« support on the mainboard - I plugged in a usb Bluetooth dongle.

I know that bluetooth is a complex thing, and I remember that I have fiddled with some of configuration in the past to somehow make the dongle work. But what I would like try in first place is to completely remove (and purge possibly spoiled config) and reinstall the whole bluetooth stack.

Just running `apt list --installed | grep blue` yields that list:

```
bluez-btsco/focal,now 1:0.50-0ubuntu7 amd64 [installed]
bluez-cups/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed]
bluez-dbg/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed]
bluez-hcidump/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed]
bluez-obexd/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed]
bluez-tests/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed]
bluez-tools/focal,now 2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-2build1 amd64 [installed]
bluez/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed]
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/focal-updates,now 3.34.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-bluetooth/focal-updates,now 3.34.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libbluetooth3-dbg/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libbluetooth3/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.53-0ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-bluetooth13/focal-updates,now 3.34.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/focal-updates,now 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 amd64 [installed]
```

So there are quite a bunch of packages involved and I am not sure if I have hit all of them. So:

Is there any command/utility or alike to reinstall the whole bluetooth stack? Is there any recommended solution to address the Problems stated above? What would be a proper place to start fixing those issues?

Due to the comments:

```
$ lsusb
[…]
Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
[…]
```

### UPDATE

I investigated more on this topic and I guess I found something that could lead to the problem:

```
# withouth the USB dongle
hciconfig 
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 24:0A:64:6F:0A:00  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:5512 acl:0 sco:0 events:379 errors:0
    TX bytes:13692 acl:0 sco:0 commands:363 errors:0

# with the usb dongle
hci1:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:08  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:694 acl:0 sco:0 events:50 errors:0
    TX bytes:3173 acl:0 sco:0 commands:50 errors:0

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 24:0A:64:6F:0A:00  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:5677 acl:0 sco:0 events:409 errors:0
    TX bytes:13877 acl:0 sco:0 commands:388 errors:0
```

Without being an expert on that, it seams that there already is a built in bluethooth device and the dongle. Running `hciconfig -a` reveals that the names, used for bluetooth are: `hostname` and `hostname #1` so these seam to be be quiet similar.

```
bluetoothctl list
Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:08 hostname #2 [default]
Controller 24:0A:64:6F:0A:00 hostname
```

Removing the dongle and running `systemctl restart bluethooth` makes the control panel display a different name in »Visiable as "…"« within the settings dialog.

Comment: Reinstalling is probably not the solution here. You may need different drives though. Please [edit] the question and post the line from `lsusb` that identifies the dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Using different Bluetooth software could help. Try installing BlueZ or BlueMan. BlueZ:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-tools
```

BlueMan:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

You can also install BlueZ from the Snap store (or the Software application)

```
sudo snap install bluez
```

To run BlueZ or BlueMan (Bluetooth Manager), you can either find it in the Ubuntu settings page, the Software page, or you can run:

Blueman:

```
blueman-manager
```

BlueZ:

```
bluez
```

If you already have BlueZ or BlueMan installed by default, or if you are currently using it, run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez bluez-tools
```

or for BlueMan

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall blueman
```