# I Accidentily removed Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

While trying to get my sony headset working with my desktop I totally removed the bluetooth stack.
I searched through several sites, and followed several sites without finding a working solution.
What steps do I have to take to get blue tooth working again?
Apologies for omitting that information. I have added the version
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: You've not provided your OS/release, thus we'd mostly be guessing. For best results, I'd reverse whatever changes you made, which you can usually remind yourself of by exploring your bash history (*if you used commands*) or *apt* logs where package removals were done.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397784/completely-reinstall-bluetooth has a list of software related to BT to install for current Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your suggestion, I wil try your suggestion examining th bash history